# What does this infinite series converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, alternating-expression

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^n(n!)}{n^n} = \space ?$

How would you figure this out? I only managed to show that it does converge and i wrote a python script that showed that it converges to roughly -0.9569682178829938.
[400th partial sum.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn0fA.png)

Comment: Why do you think it might have a closed form sum? Most series you can prove converge don't have such a sum.